# Upgrading to Rails 6.1.4 - Module in lib directory no longer found by Test class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, module, constants

I have an application that I am upgrading from Rails 5.2.6, Ruby 2.6 to Rails 6.1.4, Ruby 3.0 and am running into a problem with a class in the test directory no longer finding a module in the lib directory.  The configuration works fine in Rails 5.2.6 and I am not seeing anything in the 6.0.0 or 6.1.4 upgrade notes which clue me in on what has changed.

The configuration is as follows:

config/application.rb

```
    config.autoload_paths += %W(
      #{config.root}/lib
      #{config.root}/app/models/concerns
    )
```

lib/api.rb

```
  module Api
    URL_ID_REGEX = /(\/:([a-z_]+_id)\/)/
  end
```

test/webmock/mock.rb

```
  class Mock
    def init
      @resource_url.scan(Api::URL_ID_REGEX).each do |k, v|
       ....
       ....
       ....
      end
    end
  end
```

I am getting the error message "uninitialized constant Mock::Api", which tells me that it in Rails 6.1.4 it is trying to find the module Api under its own hierarchy.

When I change the call to:

```
      @resource_url.scan(::Api::URL_ID_REGEX).each do |k, v|
```

it simply changes the error message to "uninitialized constant Api".

I have tried including the Api module in the Mock class, but the module is never found and it always complains about the uninitialized constant.

I am aware that I can simply copy the constant definition from the module to the class and be done with it, but I would prefer to understand and resolve the problem.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to overcome this issue.

Comment: You do not need to add `#{config.root}/app/models/concerns` to the autoloading roots. Its already added. The test environment also uses eager loading so you need to add the `/lib` path to the eager loading routes as well.

Comment: You're also drawing the wrong conclusion about "uninitialized constant Mock::Api". Thats how NameError works in Ruby - the exception message contains the module nesting where it started looking for the constant. But it actually looks for the constant in Main as well.  This has absolutely nothing to do with autoloading.